# jQuery hover function with keyword: 'this'

Tags: jquery, hover, this

I have trouble understanding and using the $(this) keyword.  For example, with the hover class example from http://api.jquery.com/hover/

HTML

```
 <ul>
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>Bread</li>
    <li class='fade'>Chips</li>
    <li class='fade'>Socks</li>
</ul>

<div class='fade'>My Div<div>
```

JQUERY

This will add the function over All `<li>` elements.

```
$("li").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find("span:last").remove();
    }
);
```

If I only want to add the function over the fade class.
I was able to do it this way

```
$("li.fade").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find("span:last").remove();
    }
);
```

This selects ALL fade classes including the DIV

```
 $("li").hover(
        function () {
            $('.fade').append($("<span> ***</span>"));
        },
        function () {
            $('.fade').find("span:last").remove();
        }
    );
```

Why won't this work?

```
$("li").hover(
    function () {
        $(".fade", this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
    },
    function () {
        $(".fade", this).find("span:last").remove();
    }
);
```

I'm learning trying to learn jQuery. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried it like this?

    $(".fade", $(this)).append($("<span> ***</span>"));

Comment: Doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/W5AQV/5/

Comment: @awbergs: That doesn't make a difference. The contect can be either an element or a jQuery object containing the element, and the result is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call `$(".fade", this)` will look for elements with the class `fade` inside the element(s) represented by `this`. It does the same as `$(this).find(".fade")`.

As `this` is the element where the `hover` event is raised, which is an `li` element, it won't find anything as the class is on that element, not on any elements that are children of that element.

Comment: Wow! You answered it in seconds and it took me about 10 minutes to construct that question. Thank you so much!